# String args[] as an input for a method java

Tags: java, eclipse, args

I have this code and I am wondering what String args[] means here and how it can be used as an input I read many online comments but still confused about this thanks

```
 static int parse_commandline(String args[]) {

        // TODO range check

        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.err.println("No options are specified.");
            System.err.println("Try `--help' for more information.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption("r", "tries", true, "# number of independent trials");
        options.addOption("s", "tours", true, "# number of steps in each trial");
        options.addOption("t", "time", true, "# maximum time for each trial");
        options.addOption("seed", true, "# seed for the random number generator");}
```

Comment: Did you cut the method in the middle? It doesn't return a value.

Comment: Yes its not complete its a long code sorry

Comment: The `String args[]` in the `static` method `main` is different to the one in the method `parse_commandLine`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Yes But how I can use it as an input what will be its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String args[]` is equivalent to `String[] args`.

In other words, `args` is an array of `String`.

To know more about arrays: [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: but how this can be different from String args[] used in the main method public static void main(String[] args) because in the main method we didn't refer to this matrix and in my method I don't store any thing in this array so why I am using it what will be its value thanks

Comment: @robertjone, I would suggest picking Head First Java for You and reading it thoroughly..